# Can I change a non-resizable existing browser window with Javascript to be resizable?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Simple question, I have a window that was opened with this code

```
window.open(URL, windowName, 'resizable=no');
```

I know I can control size and position programmatically after it's loaded
but how do I make it simply **reziable again**? is there any way to override it?

(NOTE: I have no access to modify the opening code, but have full access to the child window code)

Comment: did you try setAttribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hack can be this:

```
window.open(window.location.href, document.title, 'resizable=yes');
window.close();
```

but it cause your window open a new window and close itself that is not a good UX

Comment: Since it seems the answer is widely accepted as "no", but only you provided a workaround (even though I won't necessarily use it) you deserve the accepted answer in my opinion...

Answer (score 1):

You can resize the child window like this:

```
self.resizeTo(width, height);
```

As for making the child window resizable again, I don't think you can. The parent window has control of the child.

Answer (score 1):

No, whether a window is resizable is determined when it is opened. Changing this flag after the fact isn't possible. Depending on your goal opening a new (resizable) child window and closing the old one might be an option, I don't think there are any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find it in w3c site so this might be deprecated, but [window.setResizable(true)](http://www.findmeat.org/tutorials/javascript/x676623.htm) should set it's own window resizeable.

Give it a try, check the link for more information on the restrictions.

The method is also listed [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Window-Browser/PropertiesandMethodsoftheWindowObject.htm).

Of course that, having control over the child, you could also create a new child from it I guess, as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

```
var win = window.open(URL, windowName, 'resizable=no');
win.resizeTo(*yourWidth*, *yourHeight*);
```

you can use *resizeTo* to your width and height to change the window size